# How to Complete a WebSocket Handshake in javascript(client) and java (server)?

Tags: javascript, java, html, websocket

I have wrote Websocket Client in html and javascript. and Websocket server in java.

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/websocketendpoint');
@ServerEndpoint("/websocketendpoint")
public class WebSocketExample {
```

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocketendpoint'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404

Can you please suggest how to create websocket uri and configure with the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a small project with sockJS+stomp and Spring.

You need a config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer    {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/user").withSockJS();
}
```

}

The idea is too create a controller on the server side:

```
@MessageMapping("/user")
@SendToUser("/topic/auth")
public JsonMessageWrapper process(JsonMessageWrapper jmw,
SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor)
```

On the client side you subscribe this way:

```
    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS(/*[[@{/user}]]*/); // tricky mechanism of ThymeLeaf, produces a link attached to URL of deployed webapp with proper context
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            var subscribeUrl = '/topic/auth';
            stompClient.subscribe( subscribeUrl + '-user' + socket.sessionId, function(response){
                showMessage(response.body);
            });
        });
    }
```

And this way you send a message:

```
    function send() {
        var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
        stompClient.send("/app/user", {}, message);
    }
```

P.S. I know @Transactional was used incorrectly.

Project's location https://github.com/dk2k/websocket-server